Data inserted by set in symfony appearing null
Thats my entity Empresa.php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EmpresasRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EmpresasRepository::class)]
class Empresas
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, name="nome_empresa")
     */
    private ?string $nomeEmpresa = 'batata';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", name="data")
     */
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $data = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNomeEmpresa(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nomeEmpresa;
    }

    public function setNomeEmpresa(?string $nomeEmpresa): self
    {
        $this->nomeEmpresa = $nomeEmpresa;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getData(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function setData(?\DateTimeInterface $data): self
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }
}

Thats my controller EmpresaController.php:
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Empresas;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class EmpresaController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/empresas", name="empresa_create", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        dump($requestData['nome_empresa']);

        if (!isset($requestData['nome_empresa'])) {
            return new Response('O campo "nome_empresa" é obrigatório.', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        $nome_empresa = $requestData['nome_empresa'];

        $dataAtual = new \DateTime();

        $empresa = new Empresas();
        $empresa->setNomeEmpresa($nome_empresa);
        $empresa->setData($dataAtual);

        $entityManager->persist($empresa);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return new Response('Empresa criada com sucesso: ' . $nome_empresa);
    }
}

When I fire a POST request to http://127.0.0.1:8000/empresas with the body:
{    "nome_empresa": "batata" }

It inserts the [null] field into the nome_empresa field of my table
I need to understand where the error happens.
I need to understand where the error happens

What version of Symfony and Doctrine are you using? I see that you are mixing attributes and annotations both in your entity and your Controller.
Annotaions are currently being deprecated and replaced by attributes. It is possible that your entity is not updating because of this.
